# Sections on Möbius bundle correspond to $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x+n)=(-1)^nf(x)$

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-bundles

I want to show that sections of the Möbius bundle correspond to functions 
 $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x+n)=(-1)^nf(x)$. 
Given a section of the Möbius bundle I want to define such an $f$, this will give a map from sections of the Möbius bundle into the set of desired functions.

We view $S^1$ as $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ where $\mathbb{Z}$ acts on $\mathbb{R}$ by $n\cdot x=x+n$.
We get the Mobius bundle over $S^1$ by considering the $\mathbb{Z}$ action on $\mathbb{R}^2$ that is $n\cdot(x,y)=(x+n,(-1)^n y)$. Denote the Möbius bundle by $L$.
The projection $\pi:L\rightarrow S^1$ is then $\pi(x,y)=(x)$.

Recall that a section of a line bundle over $S^1$ is a map $s:S^1\rightarrow L$ such that $\pi \circ s= id_{S^1}$.

Intuitively this makes sense but I am not sure how to rigoursly identify these things.

Given a section $s:S^1\rightarrow L$, we want to define an $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that  $f(x+n)=(-1)^nf(x)$. The $(-1)^n$ term appears when we act on $(x,y)\in L$ by $n$. So if for a section $s(x)=(s_1(x),s_2(x))$ I think we will need to define $f$ in terms of $s_2$. But this only gives $(s_1(x),s_2(x))=n\cdot(s_1(x),s_2(x))=(s_1(x)+n,(-1)^ns_2(x))$.

Do we do something like $f(x)=\pi_2(n\cdot s(\overline{x}))$? where $\overline{x}$ is the $x$ minus the nearest integer to $x$ and $n$ is the nearest integer to $x$?

This feels wrong, it seems like there should be a neater way to do this since $x+n$ and $(-1)^n$ both appear in the action of $\mathbb{Z}$/

Comment: Could be wrong, but I think $f(x+n)=(-1)^n f(x)$ is satisfied by $f(x)=\sin(\pi x).$

Comment: @AdrianKeister Unless some natural identification is being used I don't see how $sin(\pi x)$ is a section. I want to show that all sections of the mobius bundle correspond to functions satisfying $f(x+n)=(-1)^nf(x)$. This is just some function that satisfies this condition.

Comment: @Emily_257: if you say "We want to define an $f$ such that...", then the reader understands you want to find just one such function. You should change to "We want to find all $f$ such that..."

Comment: To be perfectly honest, I have not trained in vector bundles, and am completely incompetent to answer your question in terms of Möbius bundles. I thought you were asking for a function that satisfied the constraint. I cannot go further in your problem.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro We are not looking for all $f$, we are looking for a correspondence between sections and such functions. Hence we want to define a function in terms of a section. I have changed the text to more explicitly state this.

Comment: You have said that the Mobius bundle is obtained by a certain action on $\mathbb{R}^{2},$ but you have not explicitly stated how you want to take that action and get a map $L\to\mathbb{R}.$ Once you write that down, things will become a lot clearer. The space $L$ you are considering is the quotient space $\mathbb{R}^{2}/\mathbb{Z},$ and the resulting map $L\to S^{1}$ is the result of composing the projection $\mathbb{R}^{2}\to\{y=0\}\subset\mathbb{R}^{2}$ with the quotient map (so $\mathbb{R}^{2},$ $\{y=0\},$ $L$ and $S^{1}$ form a commuting square in which the vertical maps are the quotient).

Comment: @WillR I have added more details into the post, is it clear now?

Comment: A section $s\colon S^{1}\to L$ of the bundle $L\to S^{1}$ now lifts to a map $F\colon\{y=0\}\to\mathbb{R}^{2}$ which is a section of the projection $\mathbb{R}^{2}\to\{y=0\}.$ I think that $F(x,0)$ should be a point $(x,y)$ such that $n\cdot(x,y)=(x+n,(-1)^{n}y).$ The function $f$ obtained from $s$ is the composition of this lift $F$ with the second projection $\mathbb{R}^{2}\to\mathbb{R}.$ I will come back and try to make a proper, coherent answer out of these two comments a little later tonight; if the OP or anyone else figures out the details first, then I invite them to post an answer.

Comment: @Emily_257: Yes, that's correct. I don't think you need to make any more edits, but it is worth bearing in mind that when you identify $S^{1}$ as $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z},$ you really do mean $\mathbb{R}\times\{0\}/\mathbb{Z},$ i.e., you are also identifying the real line with the $x$-axis in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ (no biggie). I think these specifics of how the $S^{1}$-bundle is constructing really go a long way towards answering your question. You should bear these details in mind and try again to answer your own question (before somebody else robs you of the opportunity!).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The space $L$ is the orbit space obtained by quotienting $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ by the indicated $\mathbb{Z}$-action. That is, points of $L$ are $\mathbb{Z}$-orbits of points $(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^{2}.$ Let the orbit of $(x,y)$ be denoted $(x:y),$ so that
$$(x:y)=(x+n:(-1)^{n}y)$$
holds for all $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$ and $n\in\mathbb{Z}.$

**Lemma.** If $x,y_{1},y_{2}\in\mathbb{R}$ are such that $(x:y_{1})=(x:y_{2}),$ then $y_{1}=y_{2}.$

*Proof of lemma.* By definition, if $(x:y_{1})=(x:y_{2})$ then there must exist $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $n\cdot(x,y_{1})=(x,y_{2}).$ But $n\cdot(x,y_{1})=(x+n,(-1)^{n}y_{1}).$ Thus, we must have $n=0,$ and $y_{2}=(-1)^{n}y_{1}=y_{1}.$ $\qquad\square$

The bundle map $p\colon L\to S^{1}$ is defined a few stages. First, note that the $x$-axis in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ is invariant under the $\mathbb{Z}$-action, so that the action on $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ restricts to an action on the $x$-axis. Furthermore, on the $x$-axis the action is  by translations, i.e., $\mathbb{Z}$ acts on $\mathbb{R}\times\{0\}$ in a way which everyone knows gives $S^{1}$ as the orbit space; so we make the identification $S^{1}\cong(\mathbb{R}\times\{0\})/\mathbb{Z}.$ Finally, introduce the orthogonal projection $\pi\colon\mathbb{R}^{2}\to\mathbb{R}\times\{0\},$ and define $p=q\circ\pi.$ This gives a commuting square, in which the vertical maps are both the quotient map $q\colon\mathbb{R}^{2}\to L$ given by $q(x,y)=(x:y).$
$$
\begin{array}{ccc}
\mathbb{R}^{2} & \xrightarrow{\pi} & \mathbb{R}\times\{0\}\\
\downarrow & & \downarrow\\
L & \xrightarrow{p} & (\mathbb{R}\times\{0\})/\mathbb{Z}
\end{array}
$$

A section $s\colon(\mathbb{R}\times\{0\})/\mathbb{Z}\to L$ is just a map which satisfies $p(s(x:0))=(x:0)$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}.$ By definition of $p,$ this means that if $x\in\mathbb{R},$ then there exist a $y\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $s(x:0)=(x:y).$ We know such a $y$ is unique because of the lemma proved above. With this in mind, define $f_{s}\colon\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ by the formula $s(x:0)=(x:f_{s}(x)).$

All that remains is to check that the function $f_{s}$ so-defined satisfies the functional equation. Given $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and $n\in\mathbb{Z},$ we have
$$(x+n:f_{s}(x+n))=s(x+n:0)=s(x:0)=(x:f_{s}(x))=(x+n:(-1)^{n}f_{s}(x)).$$
Therefore $f_{s}(x+n)=(-1)^{n}f_{s}(x).$

So a (global) section $s$ of the bundle gives a function $f_{s}\colon\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ satisfying the given equation.

Comment: This is a great answer, its clear, precise and well structured. One question I would like to ask is: Is there a way to map from the quotient space $L$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$?. We have defined $f_s$ by $s(x:0)=(x:f_s(x))$. Is there a way to make a map $Q:L\rightarrow R^2$ with $Q\circ q (x:y)=(x:y)$, so that we could write $f_s(x)=\text{proj}_2 \circ Q \circ s(x:0)$?

Comment: @Emily_257: I've spent a couple of hours thinking, and I'm not sure. I think you should consider posting this as a separate question. The "obvious" section $Q(x:y)=(x-\lfloor x\rfloor,(-1)^{\lfloor x\rfloor}y)$ does not work because of $s(x:0)=(x:\cos(\pi x))$ and $x=1.$ I think it might be possible to reduce the study of a general section $Q$ to this "obvious" section by considering the geometry of the image and adjusting coordinates on $\mathbb{R}^{2},$ but I have no details (it is late here), and it would take much more than a comment to explain it (if the idea even works).

Comment: P.S.: Obviously, for a given $s$ you can take $Q_{s}(x:y)=(x,f_{s}(x)).$ I assume you are interested in the (more interesting) question of whether a $Q$ exists which is universal in the sense that it works for all $s.$